# Cocos2d js Chipmunk collision filter

Tags: cocos2d-x, collision, chipmunk

I'm using cocos2d js 3.8 with chipmunk physics, I'm trying to filter collision but it's not work, i have set 
`shape.categoryBits =1;shape.maskBits =2;`
for player and `shape.categoryBits =3;shape.maskBits =4;` for enemies
but they're still colliding. Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about js, but I think collision detection the same as in Cocos2d-x.
So, try set `shape.categoryBits = 1; shape.maskBits = 1;` for player and `shape.categoryBits = 2; shape.maskBits = 2;` for enemies. In this case, the hero should not collide the enemies, but the enemies should collide each other.
 The basic idea is the condition for the non-colliding objects:

```
(shapeA.categoryBits & shapeB.maskBits == 0) || (shapeB.categoryBits & shapeA.maskBits == 0)
```

But now you have `(0001 & 0100 == 0) || (0011 & 0010 == 0)` is false because `0011 & 0010 = 0010`, and condition is not met.